# Allow one User to Log into other Users (Sudo)

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I'd like to give a particular user the ability to log on as any normal user (e.g. not root or daemon) and execute commands as that user.

How can I do that safely?

Currently my User sudo rights on a bash script like that:

```
if [ "$1" = "run" ]; then

  sudo -u ${2} ${3};

fi
```

Which works but, security wasnt a focus.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you need access to the other users /home and other dirs or  merely a 'run as admin'-ish access? Also which distro is this one as some have extra goodies like selinux that can be used as additional safeties.

Comment: Debian, I need just run this sudo commans within /home yea

Answer (score 1):

Make a new script, `/usr/bin/runasuser`

```
#!/bin/sh
newuser="${1}" && shift
/usr/bin/sudo su - "${newuser}" -c "$@"
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/runasuser
```

Edit sudoers with command `visudo` and add this line:

```
alice ALL=(ALL)         /usr/bin/runasuser
```

This will allow Alice to run anything as Bob if she does this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/runasuser bob /opt/application/for/bob
```

Assuming your sudo environment includes /usr/bin by default, you can just run:

```
sudo runasuser bob /opt/application/for/bob
```

Comment: Do you even read? Thats basically the same stuff I already got, but not what I basically want.

Comment: Can you add some basic shell scripting to limit what username is accepted, or would you like that explained?